# Error with contour plot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code works fine

```
dat1 <- data.frame(x=c(-1,-1,1,1),y=c(-1,1,-1,1),z=c(1,2,3,4))
dat2 <- data.frame(x=c(-0.5,0.5),y=c(-0.5,0.5))

ggplot(dat1, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z)) +
geom_tile(aes(fill=z)) +
scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0, 1), low = "yellow", high = "red")
```

However, this

```
ggplot(dat1, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z)) +
geom_tile(aes(fill=z)) +
scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0, 1), low = "yellow", high = "red") +
geom_point(data=dat2, aes(x=x,y=y))
```

gives an error

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2): x, y, z

Can someone please explain why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The ggplot function will pass all of the aesthetics stated within the aes function nested within it to all geom functions that follow it. To illustrate my point both of the following work.

Cleanest answer is remove z from aes function as it is only needed for the first geom.

```
ggplot(dat1, aes(x=x, y=y) )+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=z)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0, 1), low = "yellow", high = "red") +
  geom_point(data=dat2)
```

As there is no column z in dat2 you could also explicitly state it in the aes function for geom_point

```
ggplot(dat1, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z) )+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=z)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0, 1), low = "yellow", high = "red") +
  geom_point(data=dat2, aes( z=NULL))
```

Comment: I was actually getting the error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'z' not found". Hope my answer helps any way.

Comment: Works great thanks. But why does the `geom_point()` function expect z when I've specified that the dat2 is the data source? Shouldn't that override the aes passed from `ggplot()`?

Comment: It is simply how it is designed to work. I am guessing partly because as it means in 90% of cases there is simpler looking code like my first example. If using a new data argument meant you had retype all of your aesthetics even if some were were the same then it is just generating scripts that are unnecessarily larger which I seems to be contrary to the ggplot2 tagline of being a "grammar of graphics".

Comment: @JamesBarrett the above